# Sphinx autoclass works locally, not readthedocs, but other classes and methods work on readthedocs?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I know there's several similar questions, but none of them seem to fit what is happening with me. When I build on readthedocs, it is successful. However, it doesn't show in the documentation, but will show locally. What my issue is, is that it doesn't show certain methods on readthedocs (even though there's a successful build), but it shows locally. In addition, there are certain instances where it shows neither the class and method I want it to show.

I'm not understanding what is going on and how to go about fixing it. I've made commits trying to fix it and I don't want to continue making unnecessary commits.

Links:

[Docs example 1](https://nwsapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apiref/alerts/AllAlerts.html) (class shows, method doesn't)

[Docs example 2](https://nwsapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apiref/points/Point.html) (class and method don't show, but it's setup the same as above?)

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/WxBDM/nwsapy)

Local build screenshot (what I should be seeing with the first example link): [image: local build]

Comment: Check your [build log on RTD](https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/14033026.txt) for "warning" or "error". Could be a typo of "pint" vs. "point"?

Comment: @StevePiercy Without this, I would've never figured it out. I had to add pint to requirements.txt and it now builds. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've added an answer. Would you please accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your [build log on RTD](https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/14033026.txt) for "warning" or "error".

Although I suggested that the issue could be a typo of "pint" versus "point", it turned out to be a case of needing to add `point` to `requirements.txt`.